# How to mimic the user experience of native application while building for cross mobile?

Tags: mobile, cordova

I'm building an application which I intend to deploy to iphone, android and blackberry.  There's a unique characteristic I've noticed about my blackberry bold 9700, which  uses an optical track pad for maneuvering around the screen.  As an experiment, I deployed a simple phone gap application to my blackberry.  I used the optical track pad to move a "small arrow cursor" around the screen to select and click on elements.  When I compared my experimental app to some of the other native blackberry applications on my device, I noticed that none of them use this "small arrow cursor".  Instead, sliding my thumb across the optical track pad will cause a "hi-light selector" to jump from one available link/button/field/image/list-item/tab etc... to another.   This "hi-light selector" is much faster and user-friendly than the "small arrow cursor".

Now I need advice on the best technology to achieve the following:

- I would like to write one set of code for an application to deploy to
  iOS 4+ , android 2.2+ and Blackberry OS6+
- On android and ios devices, you can simply scroll and touch buttons
  for call to actions.  On blackberry, I would like to replace the
  "small arrow cursor" with the "hi-light selector".
- I would like to use slide screen effects on android and ios devices. 
  On the blackberry, I would need a good substitute.

So my question is:  Is there a practical way for a solo developer to achieve all the criteria above?  If not, then what is the closest I can achieve to the criteria above?  And what mobile javascript library would be best for the job[1]?   Or do I really have to consider building with native technology (obj c for ios, java for android, java for bbos)?

1. I've only looked at sencha touch and didn't see anything relevant to the "hi-light selector".

Comment: Frankly, I'd put Blackberry in pretty much the same category as Nokia Meego or HP WebOS: the "circular file".  By the same token, I would *not* discount MS Windows, and the upcoming "Metro" UI:  http://www.liveside.net/2011/11/04/could-windows-8-come-to-pcs-tablets-xbox-and-windows-phone-all-next-year/

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at Appcelerator:

http://www.appcelerator.com/

... and ...

iUi:

http://www.iui-js.org/